# Stuck on transforming DNF into CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the formula

$(A \land B \implies C) \implies ((A \implies B) \land (B \implies C))$

which I have transformed into DNF:

$(A \land B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B) \lor (\neg A \land C) \lor (B \land C)$.

Now I'm stuck on tranforming this into a CNF. How could I do this? Distribution laws, de Morgan, ...? Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Construct a CNF of the negation of your formula, then negate it again using de morgan.  That makes a DNF.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try expanding the partial clauses into full clauses first using $(x \lor   \neg x \Leftrightarrow  true)$ and $(y \land true \Leftrightarrow  y)$.

**For eg:** the term $A \land \neg B$ can be expanded by $(A \land \neg B) \land (true)$ which is the same as $(A \land \neg B) \land (C \lor \neg C)$ which is the same as $(A \land \neg B \land C) \lor (A \land \neg B \lor \neg C)$ by Distributive Law.

Do this for all partial clauses.

Then, you have a Conjunction of full clauses. Now use De Morgan's law to get the equivalent disjunction of full clauses.

**Hint:** Sum of minterms = Complement of product of Maxterms.